# React AntDesign Content pushed to the side

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, antd

When I add a big Timeline into my code, the layout breaks and a margin appears on the right side. I really dont know whats causing this, it only breaks when timeline is added, tried debbuging on chromes inspect but no success.

Any ideia what could be causing this?

Im new to react and antdesign.

TSX

```
    const Dashboard = withRouter((props: any) => {
    const [menuCollapsed, setMenuCollapsed] = useState(false)
    const { authenticated } = useContext(Context);
    const { theme, changeTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

    const onCollapse = (collapsed: boolean) => {
        setMenuCollapsed(collapsed);
    };

    const toggleTheme = (active: boolean) => {
        changeTheme(active ? "dark" : "light");
    }

    const menuItemOnSelect = (res: any) => {
        history.push(`${res.keyPath[1]}${res.keyPath[0]}`);
    }

    const { location } = props;
    const locations = location.pathname.split("/").filter((i: string) => i);

    useEffect(() => breadcrumbItems(), []);

    const breadcrumbItems = () => {
        return locations.map((l: string) => {
            const breadcrumSettings = Constants.breadcrumbNames[l];
            if (breadcrumSettings && breadcrumSettings[1]) {
                const url = location.pathname;
                return (
                    <Breadcrumb.Item key={`breadcrumb-${breadcrumSettings[0]}`}>
                        <Link>{ breadcrumSettings[0] }</Link>
                    </Breadcrumb.Item>
                )
            }
        })
    }

    return (
      <Layout hasSider style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
        <Sider theme={theme} collapsible collapsed={menuCollapsed} onCollapse={onCollapse}>
          <div className={theme === "dark" ? "logo-container logo-container-dark" : "logo-container logo-container-light"}>
            <Link onClick={() => history.push(Constants.paths.dashboard)}>
                {
                    menuCollapsed ?
                    <img style={{ height: "34px" }} src={theme === "dark" ? "/logo-no-text-dark.png" : "/logo-no-text.png"} />
                    :
                    <img id="logo" src={theme === "dark" ? "/logo-sideways-dark.png" : "/logo-sideways.png"} />
                }
            </Link>
          </div>
          <Menu theme={theme} defaultSelectedKeys={['1']} mode="inline"  onSelect={menuItemOnSelect}>
            <SubMenu key="/dashboard/dimp" icon={<FileTextOutlined />} title="DIMP">
              <Menu.Item key="/mensal">Mensal</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="/retificadora">Refiticadora</Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
            <SubMenu key="sub2" icon={<FileOutlined />} title="DOC">
              <Menu.Item key="3">Mensal</Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
            <SubMenu key="sub3" icon={<CodeOutlined />} title="Admin">
              <Menu.Item key="4">Parâmetros</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="5">Agendamentos</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="6">Features</Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
        
        <Layout style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}
            // className={theme !== "dark" ? "content-container-light" : "content-container-dark"}
        >
            <Header className={theme === "dark" ? "header header-dark" : "header header-light"}>
                <Switch 
                    checkedChildren={<FiMoon fill={"white"}/>} 
                    unCheckedChildren={<FiSun fill={"white"}/>}
                    defaultChecked={theme === "dark"}
                    onChange={toggleTheme}
                />
                <Dropdown
                    overlay={
                        <Menu>
                            <Menu.Item icon={<LogoutOutlined />}>
                                Sair
                            </Menu.Item>
                        </Menu>
                    }
                    placement="bottomCenter"
                >
                    <Avatar className={"dashboard-header-avatar"}>
                            BM
                    </Avatar>
                </Dropdown>
            </Header>
                    <Content style={{backgroundColor: "blue" }}>
            {/* <Content> */}
                <Breadcrumb>
                    { [<Breadcrumb.Item>Dashboard</Breadcrumb.Item>, ...breadcrumbItems()] }
                </Breadcrumb>
                <Title level={4} style={{ marginTop: "15px", marginBottom: "30px" }}>
                    { 
                        locations.map((l: string) => {
                            const breadcrumSettings = Constants.breadcrumbNames[l];
                            if (breadcrumSettings) return breadcrumSettings[0];
                        }).join(" ")
                    }
                </Title>
                <Timeline>
                            <Timeline.Item color="green">DIMP Outubro finalizada</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item dot={<CodeOutlined style={{ fontSize: '16px' }} />}>
                                23/11/2021: Fase <Text italic > Geração das origens concluída</Text> concluída
                            </Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>23/11/2021: Geração dos informes DIMP iniciada</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item dot={<CodeOutlined style={{ fontSize: '16px' }} />}>
                                17/11/2021: Fase <Text italic > Envio das Origens</Text> concluída
                            </Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>17/11/2021: Remessa completa recebida (EV8)</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item color="red">15/11/2021: Remessa inconsistente recebida (EV8)</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>13/11/2021: Remessa completa recebida (BS1)</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item color="red">12/11/2021: Remessa inconsistente recebida (BS1)</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item color="red">12/11/2021: Remessa inconsistente recebida (EV8)</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item color="red">10/11/2021: Remessa inconsistente recebida (EV8)</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>05/11/2021: Remessa completa recebida (MY1)</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>05/11/2021: Remessa completa recebida (UR1)</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                            <Timeline.Item>01/11/2021: Processo DIMP mensal inicidado</Timeline.Item>
                        </Timeline>
                </Content>
            {/* </Content> */}
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    );
});
```

SCSS

```
    .logo-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 55px;
    
    &-light {
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    }
    
    &-dark {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #66737f;
    }
}

.header {
    height: 55px;
    
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right;
    display: flex;

    &-light {
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    }

    &-dark {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #66737f;
    }

}

  #logo {
      height: 50px;
   }

.content-container-light {
    // background-color: white;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.content-container-dark {
    background-color: #3e4756;
    padding: 0;
    height: "100%"
}

.dashboard-content {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
}

.dashboard-content-container {
    background-color: blue;
    // margin: 20px 40px;
}

.dashboard-header-avatar {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I had a wrapper on top of my App component with these properties:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <div id='main-container'>
      <App/>
    </div>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
#main-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```